# How to see the CLI generated by Wildfly web interface

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly

Using Wildfly, I want to use the CLI to execute common tasks [with a script](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/CLI+Recipes#CLIRecipes-ScriptedConfiguration).

Usually, I use the web interface and I know how it works. Let's say I want to create a datasource with the web interface. Is there a way to look at a generated CLI, so that I can use it later for a script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way. The web console doesn't generate CLI commands it generates [DMR](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Detyped+management+and+the+jboss-dmr+library) which is a detyped management model similar to JSON.

CLI does the same thing. It takes CLI commands and converts them to DMR operations.

The CLI does have tab complete which might help you. Some helpful operations are `read-operation-names`, `read-resource-description` and `read-operation-description`.

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=*:read-operation-names
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=*:read-operation-description(name=add)
```

For data sources there's actually a `data-source` command. You can get more information by executing `data-source --help`.